# Apple Studio Display - External SSD gets hot

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, mac-studio

I have an external SSD plugged into the Studio Display. When I need to disconnect my laptop, I unmount the SSD first before unplugging the laptop. Now the SSD is only connected to the Studio Display. When I come back later to dock my laptop, the SSD is quite warm.

Any ideas? I was thinking maybe the SSD is confused and is repeatedly looking for a machine while connected to the display? Surely this is shortening the SSD's life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so that the SSD gets confused and tries to look for a machine. That's simply now how SSDs work.

It does seem that your SSD is drawing power while connected to the display, and as a consequence becomes warmer. However, SSDs are usually rated to function without any consequences at warm temperatures.

For example a popular SSD like the Samsung T7 Portable SSD has its specifications listed with operating temperature up to 60 degrees C. So unless you're actually burning yourself holding the SSD, it's not really getting too hot.

You will need to find out what kind of SSD you have, look up its specs, and then determine if the temperature you observe is within specs.

Comment: just so happens that my SSD is the one you mentioned (T7). Thanks for resolving my concerns!